# str to date query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

In MySQL am getting error for above. Error is : Incorrect datetime value '31/July/2018' for function str to date

```
Update mytable
set Date1 = STR_TO_DATE('31/July/2018', '%d/%b/%Y')
where 'Date' IS NOT NULL;
```

Need  help with what could be wrong with above.

Comment: Did you read the manual?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `%b`:

> %b    Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec)

You need `%M`:

> %M    Month name in full (January to December)

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Atleast link to official mysql docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date format is explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Re source: there are people who know how these functions are supposed to work, and there are people who simply copy the stuff. You decide.

Comment: @maio290 Some people [don't like w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com), there was even a dedicated website called [w3fools](https://www.w3fools.com/) listing all the faults there